# NullPointerException in sessionFactory.openSession

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets

I'm developing a web application using Spring Hibernate. At there I have a method in DAO class.

When I call it through a jsp file it works well. But When I call it through servlet it gives a `NullPointerException`. Below I put the method.

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Employee> listEmployees() {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();//line 95
    Criteria crit= session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("EmployeeId",2 ));
    List<Employee> employeelist= crit.list();
    session.close();
    return employeelist;

}
```

Below is how I call it.

```
public void getConfirm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) { 

Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()).warning("Inside Confirm Servlet");  
    response.setContentType("text/html"); 

    // do some works

    EmployeeDao employeeDao=new EmployeeDao();
    employeeDao.listEmployees();         //line 55

    }
```

This is my sessionFactory configuration

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>abc.model.Employee</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties" >

            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And This is the error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ConfirmServlet] in context with path[/Spring3Hibernate] threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at abc.dao.EmployeeDao.listEmployees(EmployeeDao.java:95)
    at abc.mail.ConfirmServlet.getConfirm(ConfirmServlet.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Could you please tell me how to solve this because I want to call it through servlet.

Comment: Exception states `sessionFactory` is referencing to a `null`, where as it expects `SessionFactory` object. Check your `sessionFactory` obejct initialization.

Comment: How you define `sessionFactory` ?

Comment: Can you share your sessionFactory configuration and injection code to EmployeeDaoImpl class?

Comment: You are constructing your own instance of you dao (not managed by spring) and expect spring to magically to inject the dependencies. Autowire the dependencies and if that isn't possible use the application context to retrieve the spring configured instance. Also use `getCurrentSession` instead of `openSession` and have spring manage your sessions by applying correct declarative transaction management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I call it through a jsp file it works well.

Its working because you have this statement defined in your DAO:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

And the DAO instance on which the `listEmployees` method was called is a Spring managed bean and the Spring managed `SessionFactory` that you have defined in your configuration file has already been injected into your DAO bean.

> But When I call it through servlet it gives a NullPointerException

This is not working:

```
EmployeeDao employeeDao=new EmployeeDao();
employeeDao.listEmployees();
```

Because the `EmployeeDao` instance on which `listEmployees` is being called is not a Spring managed bean. Its just a new instance of `EmployeeDao`. So the `SessionFactory` instance that you have in your `EmployeeDao` is `null`.

Now, if you want to inject your Spring managed `EmployeeDao` into your Servlet, you can do this by overriding the Servlet's `init` method as below:

```
private EmployeeDao ed;
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext());
    ed = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("employeeDao");
}
```

You can now re-write `getConfirm` method to this:

```
public void getConfirm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) { 

Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()).warning("Inside Confirm Servlet");  
    response.setContentType("text/html"); 

    // do some works

    //EmployeeDao employeeDao=new EmployeeDao();
    employeeDao.listEmployees();         //line 55

    }
```

**EDIT:**

Make these entries into your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/your-spring-config-file.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understood the fault. When I tried your solution it gives error in line
ApplicationContext context =WebApplicationContextUtils...

Error is

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84)
 at net.pearson.mail.ConfirmServlet.init(ConfirmServlet.java:38)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)...

Answer (score 0):

Include below line of code before line 95. Assuming that you havent created SessionFactory object

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
//Your operation
Session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: I tried it too. When I use it it stops giving error. But doesn't pass any value.

Comment: i updated my code,try this way,let me notify if any error is still there

Answer (score 0):

For me, the mapping attribute in `hibernate.cfg.xml` was pointing to incorrect Model.